# Do Borg Drones dream while regenerating?

Tags: star-trek, borg

We know that Seven of Nine had dreams, but she wasn't fully Borg. I'm curious whether anything in the canon answers the question of whether Borgs dream while regenerating.

Comment: we know there were a whole group of borg drones that would enter some "dreamworld" were they would be individuals again. i cant remeber if that was the result of something voyager did or if voyager used that against the borg.

Comment: @Himarm - You're referring to Unimatrix Zero; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimatrix_Zero. It was created by a group of drones who happened to be resistant to Borg mind control *when dreaming*.

Comment: She wasn't fully borg?

Comment: Not while a member of Janeway's space gang.

Comment: @Richard I haven't seen the episode(s) where Unimatrix Zero is dealt with.  Does it say whether those resistant Borg dreamed (and thus entered Unimatrix Zero) *because* they were resistant, or whether all Borg dreamed and these simply experienced something special while doing so?

Comment: @Nerrolken - The first one. They dreamed because they were resistant.

Comment: Suggestion for a new question title: Do Borg dream of assimilated sheep?

Comment: @Richard, Specifically, as I recall, it was a mutation in those drones which was granting them access to Unimatrix Zero.

Comment: @HorusKol - Assimilated chickens, surely? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47154/borg-naming-conventions/47171#47171

Comment: @calccrypto did she look like it? Hahaha no. She had tons of pieces removed. Each piece removed would move her away from borg towards humanity. I mean she was pretty darn human looking to me towards the end.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you mean by dream, and who you want to include as Borg.

From the TV shows, it would seem that your regular Borg drone would not dream in the sense of what you or I would dream - they are always part of the collective, and even when regenerating they are sensitive to the voices of the other Borg speaking in unison.

We do see some irregular cases, though - Borg that become separated from the collective, like the Unimatrix Zero Borgs, or Seven of Nine. And we certainly see Seven dreaming in at least a couple of episodes.

Comment: I was referring to Borg Drones that are still fully incorporated into the Collective. Seven wasn't fully Borg, and I don't think the Unimatrix Zero Borgs were, either.

Comment: "it would seem that your regular Borg drone would not dream"

Comment: @T-1000 - the unimatrix zero Borgs were fully incorporated (originally), until the humans interfered with a virus that separated them from the collective. The Borg queen was quite explicit as far as losing voices in that episode.